# Keep the check boxes after the setter holdings

Tags: jquery, prestashop

I would like to keep the status of the checkboxes once they have checked.
in the normal state that's what it looks like.

[image: nochecked]

I check the 2 boxes and I would like it to be 2 boxes to remain checked when I click on "Save customization"

[image: checked]

Currently when I check and I save my 2 checkboxes this check and so my quantity goes down to 1. Here is my current JS code.

```
    function checkedUsers() {
    $('#quantity_wanted').val($(':checkbox:checked').length);
    $('.product-message').val(
        $(":checkbox:checked").map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(', ')
    );
}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: cant able to understand your question.\

Comment: I try to keep the status of the box to (check) once the form validate.

Comment: How have you added these checkboxes?